# XML node type issue

Tags: xml, xslt

What is difference between these 4 types of XML nodes and when to use each of them?

- element
- text node
- comments
- instruction node

EDIT 1: whether my below understanding of text node is correct?

in the below sample, text node is abcd?

```
<foo>abcd</foo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reference is really good this page [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) but if you are looking for some tutorials it probably won't be right one.

Comment: From the link, where it is mentioned XML node types? I read it again and cannot find out.

Comment: Appreciate if you could review EDIT 1 section of my post to see whether my understanding is correct (about XML text node)?

Comment: This page is usable like a reference for XSLT commands and instructions. It is not about XML. 

Your Edit 1: yes, text node is "abcd" and in XPath it's called `text()`. Element is "foo" and in XPath it is also `*` which matches all elements. 

I am sorry but I don't know any page with XML tutorial etc. because I know it from school and I have never required other information.

Answer (score 1):

The best reference I've found for XSLT is '[XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0, 4th Edition](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/XSLT-2-0-and-XPath-2-0-Programmer-s-Reference-4th-Edition.productCd-0470192747.html)' by [Michael Kay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Kay_(software_engineer)). He's the spec lead for xslt 2.0 and xpath 2.0 and the implementor of the [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) XSLT engine. It really is a great book - my copy has floated around the whole team and always has the answer if you look hard enough.

Another tip is to include the authors name in your xslt related search. He's quite active on the XSLT mailing list and including his name in the search term helps you jump straight to the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Hi cb, thanks! Actually I do not have the book at hand. For my specific question about XML node types, do you have any good ideas or recommended documents (e.g. some kinds of short document to answer my specific question, like a blog?)? :-)

Comment: Appreciate if you could review EDIT 1 section of my post to see whether my understanding is correct (about XML text node)?